# How to put a column heading at the top of a column break using css column-count

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

I am outputting a list to a content div and want it to flow into x columns - whatever will fit in the content div. But css makes you specify the number of columns. I would also like to put a heading at the top of each column:

```
Firstname  Lastname  State     Firstname  Lastname  State     Firstname  Lastname  State
Jon        Smith     NY        Lisa       Jones     FL        Rich       Ford      TX
Linda      Steele    TN        Rick       Perry     VA        Lee        Linders   OH
```

I can get it to go to multi-column with column-count, but what I would like to do is flow into as many columns as will fit (float??) and put a header at the top. Probably this is not possible using CSS only and I will have to code a bit. But I thought I would ask if anyone had a different approach / recommendations.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I thought CSS allowed it to be auto: **[W3C CSS3 Column-count](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_column-count.asp)**. Haven't used `auto`, but looks like it's an option.

Granted, I don't know exactly what you're trying to accomplish, but it would seem that it'd make more sense to put it in a table of some sorts. Why wouldn't you want put all the First Names in the same column (and other similar headings).

Comment: I have only a few columns and more width than height in this content box. So if I can fit another column of items to the right of the first columns, it makes sense for the particular data I am working with. Thanks for the info! I will take a look.